# How can I paginate data from different database's table in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, multiple-databases

I have two database users and magento.
magento is reside at remote machine in LAN.
and users is reside at my local machine.

connection between them and fetching data from that magento database is working fine
but I want to do pagination on magento's table data.
simple displaying it is done, but for pagination we require model name, and how can i have model of other database??

```
          // in controller action
           $this->Vendor->changeDataSource('vsdatabase');
            if($this->changeDbSource('vsdatabase'))
            {
                $magento_data = $this->Vendor->query("SELECT * from admin_user");
                $this->set('products',$magento_data);
            }

          and changeDataSource($newdb) is defined in model file
         and changeDbSource($database='default') in controller
```

so how can I solve my problem  with pagination?
I have completed fetching data without pagination.
or any other option to do this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way..

You should create a new database configuration for the external database, call it say.. `$vendor_db` in `app/config/database.php`

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/922/Database-Configuration

Then you need a model for your new connection. Tell the model what database connection to use with `$useDBConfig`:

```
class Vendor extends AppModel {
    var $useDbConfig = 'vendor_db';
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1058/useDbConfig

This way, in your Vendors controller you can make database calls using standard cakePHP functions, including paginate.

`$this->paginate('Vendor')`

cakePHP model functions should almost always preclude you from writing your own queries. Generally speaking, if you think you have to write a query, you're probably doing something wrong.